# Adding a parameter in a python function when used as Keras model for random search

Tags: python, function, keras, deep-learning, hyperparameters

I do have the following functions, used for a random search with Keras

```
def mymodel(hp):
    
    hp_count = hp.Int('cnt_' , min_value=4, max_value=32, step=4)

rsearch = RandomSearch(
    mymodel,
    ....
)
```

I need to loop inside the function using an external parameter.
I tried

```
def mymodel(hp,n):
    for i in range(0,n)
        hp_count = hp.Int('cnt_' + str(i), min_value=4, max_value=32, step=4)
```

or

```
def mymodel(hp):
    n = hp.Int('n', min_value=1, max_value=4, step=1)
    for i in range(0,n)
        hp_count = hp.Int('cnt_' + str(i), min_value=4, max_value=32, step=4)
```

none of the solutions do work. In fact I am stuck with the initial approach.
Any one having a hint ? A solution ?

Comment: Did you look at `functools.partial`?

Comment: hi, no. don(t know it.will look

Comment: just di. It seems that it set the value of existing parameter. not setting extra

Comment: Probably I misunderstood your problem. _none of the solutions do work_ is not clear statement of your problem. Please, elaborate. Check [ask]. What did not work, did you get errors, etc.